Replace all elements of matrix with $x$ in minimum steps
This question was asked in a recent online assessment:
You are given an $n \times m$ matrix that contains $k$ unique elements. In one step, you can choose an element, and all occurrences of that element in the same row or column will be replaced with $x$. Your goal is to replace all elements in the matrix with $x$.

Task: Determine the minimum number of steps required to replace all elements in the matrix with $x$.
Eg:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
In step 1 it becomes (choose $(2,3)$ element)
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & x \\
x & x & x \\
1 & 2 & x
\end{bmatrix}
In step 2 (choose $(1,1)$ element)
\begin{bmatrix}
x & x & x \\
x & x & x \\
x & 2 & x
\end{bmatrix}
In step 3 (choose $(3,2)$ element)
\begin{bmatrix}
x & x & x \\
x & x & x \\
x & x & x
\end{bmatrix}
The constraints are $1 \leq n,m \leq 100$ and $1\leq k \leq 50$.
My Approach:
1.Treat all the unique elements separately.
2.Create a graph for each unique element by connecting 2 nodes if they are in the same row or column.
3. We maintain an array of indegree. In each step we choose the maximum indegree element (let this be denoted by $i$) and traverse all the nodes connected to it (let these be denoted by $j$'s where $j$ and $i$ have an edge). When we do so we reduce the indegree of all the nodes attached to the $j$ nodes by $-1$ each. The indegree of the main node $i$ and it's adjacent $j$ will be assigned value $0$. We repeat this step unless all the nodes are visited.
Now I'm unable to proceed from here.(I'm thinking of a greedy approach but unable to frame it.)
The algorithm should be of the order less than $O(n \cdot m \cdot k)$

Can you credit the original source where you encountered this problem?

It was asked in the online asssessment of a company. But I'm not sure about the company name as it was asked to me by a friend

You idea to consider each of $k$ values separately makes sense.
If any number of choices is good enough, then greedy approach makes sense. But your graph potentially has too many edges. Indeed for $n \times m$ matrix consisting of equal elements you have $nm$ vertices and $nm \cdot (n - 1 + m - 1) / 2$ edges, since every vertex has degree $n - 1 + m - 1$. However another greedy approach could be implemented in the following way.
Suppose we consider value $v$. Count number of values $v$ for each row. Then iteratively find the first row with non-zero number of elements and choose the first element in this row. Replace $v$ by $x$ for every element in the same row and column. Replacing an element decrease the number of elements in corresponding row.
Counting number of values $v$ takes $\mathrm{O}(nm)$ times. After that each iteration takes $\mathrm{O}(n + m)$ time. And the number of iterations is upper-bounded by $\min\{\,n, m\,\}$, because every row and every column may be selected only once. Summing up and multiplying by number $k$ of different values we get $\mathrm{O}(nmk)$ as desired.
Anyway if you want to minimize the number of choices then greedy approach based on choosing every time the most efficient element fails on the following example:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & \cdot & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \cdot
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Indeed choosing $(1, 1)$ we leave ones in $(2, 3)$ and $(3, 2)$ only, that requires two more choices. On the other hand choosing $(1, 3)$ and $(3, 1)$ allows to use $2$ steps only.
And this problem is $\mathrm{NP}$-hard, because it is equivalent to the minimum maximal matching in a bipartite graph. Two edges having a vertex in common are called adjacent. A matching is a subset of edges, which are pairwise non-adjacent. A matching is called maximal if it is not a proper subset of any other matching. The minimum maximal matching problem is to find a maximal matching of minimum cardinality. Its decision version is known to be $\mathrm{NP}$-complete even for bipartite graphs.
Now let's show that our problem with matrix is equivalent to MINIMUM MAXIMAL MATCHING for bipartite graphs. Given a bipartite graph we suppose vertices of one part to be rows, vertices of another part to be columns and edges to be equal elements. Choosing an element is equivalent to adding an edge to the matching. Every adjacent edge becomes unavailable to be added to the matching as well as every element in the same row or column can't be chosen. Thus a set of chosen elements is equivalent to a matching and since every should be either chosen of be in the same row or column with a chosen one, then a final set of chosen elements is equivalent to a maximal matching. If we minimize the number of choices then we minimize cardinality of maximal matching as well. Due to polynomiality of this reduction we get that the problem of minimum number of choices is $\mathrm{NP}$-hard.

Can you suggest me resources on this topic as its quite new to me and I would like to learn more on this.

And @Smylic could you please work out the example given. According to my understanding your process would lead to an answer 4,while correct answer should be 3.

@MdKaifFaiyaz In algorithms theory one of the best book is Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein. In complexity theory: Computers and Intractability — A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness by Michael R. Garey, David S. Johnson. And practice solving algorithmic problems on some platforms like codechef, topcoder, codeforces, leetcode etc. Start with trivial and easy problems and go higher

@MdKaifFaiyaz Yes, it will often give non-optimal solution. Proving $\mathrm{NP}$-hardness I explain why it is impossible to give optimal solution in polynomial time (unless $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$)
